# C++ Circular Construction Issue

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with an assignment. I have a class called Grid and Record. Record is Grid that stores how many times each position in a Grid has been accessed. Grid must contain a data member of type Record that can store whenever a change is made to Grid. I've managed to avoid a circular dependancy, but I seem to have a problem with a "circular construction" leading to a stack overflow. Calling the Grid constructor makes a Record, which creates a Grid, which tries to make another Record and so on. My first thought was to make Grid's Record data member a pointer which I initialize to NULL, then actually create the Record object outside of the constructor, however the assignment specifically says Grid's Record data member must be of type Record, not a pointer to a Record. I am also not allowed to give Record a default constructor, so I'm guessing my implementation is wrong. Any suggestions for how I can solve this problem?

```
Record::Record(int rows, int cols) : grid(new Grid(rows, cols)) {};

Grid::Grid(int rows, int cols) : record(new Record(rows, cols)) {};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is simply a misunderstanding in the assignment, or that it was written poorly.

It seems that what you want:

```
Grid
+---+---+-
| a | b |
+---+---+-
| c | d |
+---+---+-

Record
+---+---+-
| 0 | 1 |
+---+---+-
| 2 | 2 |
+---+---+-
```

Which indicates that `a` has not been accessed and `d` has been accessed twice.

Now, if a `Grid` should contain a `Record` to maintain its statistics, then a `Record` cannot be a `Grid`. As you noticed it is circular. However, `Record` is a grid. So I suspect there is a typo/reading issue here.

My suggestion:

```
class Record {
public:
  Record(size_t rows, size_t cols): rows(rows), cols(cols), grid(rows*cols, 0) {}

private:
  size_t rows;
  size_t cols;
  std::vector<size_t> grid;
};


template <typename E>
class Grid {
public:
  Grid(size_t rows, size_t cols): grid(rows*cols, 0), record(rows, cols) {}

private:
  std::vector<E> grid;
  Record record;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what type of design structure you are going with, but here is one solution to your problem. Instead of creating a new whatever, just have the constructor of the "inner" take a pointer to the "outer"(terms described later).

So, it would be

```
Record::Record(int rows, int cols) : grid(new Grid(rows, cols,this) {}; //outer

Grid::Grid(Record* master) : record(master) {}; //inner
```

The "outer" class is the one that the users should be using.

The "inner" class is the one that you have for implementation reasons(or for things like iterators and inheritance).

Swap around the constructors so that the above style is followed. A user should never have to do: `Grid f(new Record(rows,cols));`

Note that is almost a very rough approximation of inner classes in java.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the arguments for the constructors unfortunately. Grid and Record must both take two arguments that are ints.

Comment: @Slipflurry Does the Record need a reference to Grid? I think it's almost impossible(without bad trickery) to have a reference back without an extra parameter. Perhaps the assignment was written incorrectly.

Comment: You may be right. It's a bit odd that seemingly the only solution would be to copy everything from the Grid class into Record so that it no longer references Grid...

Comment: @Slipflurry  : Yout dont need to copy everything. Maybe you can use inheritante to have a Grid(simply a grid) and a GridWithRecord(a Grid that also have record functionality).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make Record have a virtual function that actually does the recording and then have Grid simply be a type of Record and then overwrite the recording function.  Something like:

```
class Record
{
  virtual recordSomething();
}

class Grid : Record
{
  virtual recordSomething();
}
```

I don't know if I understand enough of your issue, but I think this should help.  Good luck.